# Change the shadow color to any other color in THREE?

Tags: three.js

It this possible? If so, I can't seem to locate any documentation around it.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665657/customizing-shadow-color

Comment: Have a look at this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=light#webgl_lights_spotlights).

Comment: These are opposing ideas. I believe the first is saying that you cannot while the link to the second "appears" you can?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that to a limited amount by using a `THREE.ShadowMaterial` for the objects receiving the shadow. You might need to have a separate renderpass for shadow-rendering though. See here for an example:

https://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/JrZOPw

Answer (score 0):

Yes, alter the color of your shadow plane's material. I needed a slightly blue-ish tint to my shadows so used something like this:

```
var material = new THREE.ShadowMaterial({opacity: .7, color: '#003'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding ambient light can lighten the color of the shadows. It illuminates all the objects in the scene including the shadows.

```
// Create an ambient light, and set its intensity
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
ambientLight.intensity = 0.5;// max=1
```

...

```
// Add the ambient light to the scene
scene.add(ambientLight);
```

...

Try experimenting with different values to get the desired effects. You may need to adjust the intensity of your light source to get the best result.